Unit test project is not finding extension methods
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace PdbLib
{
    public static class AssertExtensions
    {
        public static void AssertVec3Equal(this Assert assert, Vec3 expected, Vec3 actual, double tolerance, string message = "")
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(expected.DistanceTo(actual) <= tolerance, message);
        }

        public static void AssertVec3NotEqual(this Assert assert, Vec3 expected, Vec3 actual, double tolerance, string message = "")
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(expected.DistanceTo(actual) > tolerance, message);
        }

        public static void AssertVec3Equal2(this Assert assert, Vec3 expected, Vec3 actual, double tolerance, string message = "")
        {
            if (Math.Abs(expected.X - actual.X) >= tolerance)
            {
                throw new AssertFailedException($"{message} X-component is incorrect. Expected: {expected.X}, Actual: {actual.X}");
            }

            if (Math.Abs(expected.Y - actual.Y) >= tolerance)
            {
                throw new AssertFailedException($"{message} Y-component is incorrect. Expected: {expected.Y}, Actual: {actual.Y}");
            }

            if (Math.Abs(expected.Z - actual.Z) >= tolerance)
            {
                throw new AssertFailedException($"{message} Z-component is incorrect. Expected: {expected.Z}, Actual: {actual.Z}");
            }
        }
    }
}

I have kept this class in a unit-test project and named it unit_test_library.
Then, I added unit_test_library library as a reference to the actual unit test projects.
However, those projects are not finding these functions as members of the Assert class.
What is the issue?
I am using:

Visual Studio 2017
.NET Framework 4.7.2

Example usage:
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using PdbLib; 

namespace PdbLibTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class HingeMoversTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MakePredefinedMove()
        {
            MakePredefinedMoveN(1);
            //MakePredefinedHingeMoveN(7);
            //MakePredefinedHingeMoveN(8);
        }

        private void MakePredefinedMoveN(int hingeMoveSize)
        {
            int residue_count = 3;

            // Setup random generator
            Random random = new Random(42);
            PdbLib.System model = PdbLib.System.MakeRandom(new int[] { residue_count }, 100.0, random);

            // Initialize internal coordinates
            double[] r = new double[residue_count];
            double[] planar = new double[residue_count];
            double[] dihedral = new double[residue_count];
            Vec3[] coords = new Vec3[residue_count];

            for (int i = 0; i < residue_count; i++)
            {
                r[i] = 1.0;
                planar[i] = (90.0).ToRadian();
                dihedral[i] = (180.0).ToRadian();
                coords[i] = new Vec3();
            }

            NeRF.RestoreLinearChain(r, planar, dihedral, ref coords);//(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0)

            for (int i = 0; i < residue_count; i++)
            {
                model.Vec3ToCa(i, coords[i]);//(0,0,0), (42949672, 0, 0), (42949672, 42949672, 0)
            }

            AtomMover mover = new AtomMover(hingeMoveSize, Math.PI / 2.0, Math.PI / 2.0);
            MoveProposal mp = new MoveProposal(hingeMoveSize);//(0,0,0)

            Vec3 v0Before = model.CaToVec3(0);//0,0,0
            Vec3 v1Before = model.CaToVec3(1);//1,0,0
            Vec3 lastBefore = model.CaToVec3(hingeMoveSize + 1);//1,1,0

            mover.ComputeMove(model, 1, Math.PI / 2, ref mp);//mp = (42949672, 0, -30370005)
            mp.Apply(ref model);//model = (0,0,0), (42949672, 0, -30370005), (42949672,42949672,0)

            Vec3 v0After = model.CaToVec3(0);//0,0,0
            Vec3 v1After = model.CaToVec3(1);//1,0,0
            Vec3 lastAfter = model.CaToVec3(hingeMoveSize + 1);//1,1,0

            Assert.AssertVec3Equal(v0Before, v0After, 1e-5, "First CA should remain unchanged.");
            Assert.AssertVec3Equal(lastBefore, lastAfter, 1e-5, "Last CA should remain unchanged.");
            
            double dihedralMovedDegrees = Vec3Helper.DihedralAngle4(v1Before, v0Before, lastBefore, v1After).ToDegrees();

            Assert.AreEqual(90.0, Math.Abs(dihedralMovedDegrees), 0.01, "Dihedral angle should change by 90 degrees.");
        }        
    }
}


Add an example usage, please. I have a suspicion.

@Fildor, added.

Ok, confirmed. Extension methods are defined static, but you call them on instances. You cannot call them statically (as static method of the extended type).

^^ I'd just make that static method in a type called AssertEx or something like that.

To clarify change public static void AssertVec3NotEqual(this Assert assert... to public static void AssertVec3NotEqual(Vec3 expected, Vec3 actual, double tolerance, string message = "") then just use AssertVec3Equal(...) as a regular static method, not off the Assert static instance. An extension method extends an Instance of the target, not another static instance or type. I.e. string test ="test"; test.MyExtension(); not string.MyExtension();

If you define extension methods for the Assert class of MsTest, you should use them via the That property of this class. In your case, this is
Assert.That.AssertVec3NotEqual(vector1, vector2, tolerance);

If you omit the Assertfrom the name of the method, you will even get a phrase that reads like an English sentnece: Assert that vec3 are not equal.
See also the documentation: https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/main/RFCs/002-Framework-Extensibility-Custom-Assertions.md
